# Trying to change object ID from Name to Automatic Number

Tags: auto-number

I am getting an error when trying to change a custom object's unique field from a Name to Auto #.  I made sure that all the current Names are #'s.

[image]

Comment: Do all records have a value? Are those values unique? Try `select field from object where field = null limit 1` and `select field from object group by field having count(field) > 1`. If you get a result for either query, you may need to fix those values first. In addition, how long was the original field length? If you have any field values greater than 30 characters, you will need to truncate those values (try changing the field length to 30 or less).

Comment: This is the Name field on a custom object that is either set to Text or AutoNumber.  There was text in the field for 530 records.  I updated the field values to be numbers while the data type was still text.  Now all the records have a unique number in the field - although the field is still a text data type.  When I try to convert the field to autonumber, I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in Classic trying to change the data type from Text to AutoNumber, I received a more informative error message.  The message indicated that a matching rule was preventing the data type change.  Once I removed the matching rule, I was able to change the data type.